# $\int^{2 \pi}_0 \frac{1}{3+2 \cos t}dt$ using $\cos t = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{it} + \frac{1}{e^{it}}\right)$ or using $u=\tan \frac{t}{2}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

> Question : Compute the integral of $$\int^{2 \pi}_0 \frac{1}{3+2\cos t}dt$$

I am stucked on this problem since a good while. I think we could convert that real integral into complex integral and using the identity $\cos t = \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{it} + \frac{1}{e^{it}}\right)$. Some people told me that integral become easy if we use the change of variable $u=\tan \frac{t}{2}$, but I don't know how. Is there someone who could solve this problem for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that $u$ blows up at $t=\pi$, and is not a bijection on $[0,2\pi]$, so you will have to be careful about how you make that substitution.

Comment: Use the substitution $u = \tan{\frac{t}{2}}$. Then try to write $ \cos{t} $  and $\frac{dt}{du}$ in terms of $u$.

Comment: @Wolfups This is a part of my problem. Could you explain to me how to do that?

Comment: @george try using the identity $\cos{x} = 2\cos^2{\frac{x}{2}}- 1$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the usual identity $cos t = \dfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}$. You also have, by the chain rule, $du = \dfrac{1}{2}(1+u^2)dt$. Thus \begin{align*} \int_0^\pi \dfrac{1}{3+2\cos t} dt & = \int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{3+2\left(\dfrac{1-u^2}{1+u^2}\right)}\dfrac{2}{1+u^2}du \\ &= \int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{2 du}{5+u^2} \\ &= \left[\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{5}} \mathrm{Arctan}\left(\dfrac{u}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right]_0^{+\infty} \\ &=\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{5}}
\end{align*}

Similarly $\displaystyle \int_\pi^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{3+2\cos t} dt = \dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{5}}$. So $\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \dfrac{1}{3+2\cos t} dt = \dfrac{2\pi}{\sqrt{5}}$.

Comment: As Wolfups noticed, it is cleverer to first translate to $[-\pi,\pi]$ instead of computing two integrals...

Answer (score 0):

Hint $cos(t)=\frac{1-tan^2(t/2}{1+tan^2(t/2)}$ so integral becomes $\int \frac{sec^2(t/2)}{5+tan^2(t/2)
}$ .